# Failed to register bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, certificado-apple

Existe alguna forma de firmar o compilar una aplicación con un bundle identifier que se encuentre ya registrado en otra cuenta de apple developer [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Debes ingresar la otra cuenta en Xcode:

1. Preferences -> Accounts.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Una vez logueado te aparecen las opciones para descargar los certifcados y perfiles.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Instalas haciendo doble click en los archivos descargados y revisas que se encuentren en el KeyChain.
4. Compilas el proyecto con `⌘ + B`.